# How do I launch/debug a project in an external console?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug a Go project in VSCode. I am able to debug it, but the application is running in the internal VSCode terminal. I need the application to run in an external console instead. For instance I want it to run in cmd.exe.

```
// .vscode/launch.json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${fileDirname}"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I make the debug session open a external console and run it there, rather than in the internal console of VSCode?

Comment: Ah, they're working on it :) https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/124#issuecomment-1006122877

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developers for the Go VSCode extension are in the process of adding a launch property for this. See: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/124#issuecomment-1006122877